# Textbox Highlight red when no data inside it using javascript validation

Tags: javascript, html, umbraco4

I have a Text-box which highlights red when I click on it (on focus). If I type anything inside it it highlights back to grey. But When I type something inside it and again delete all the data inside it doesn't highlight back to red. Please help me with it. Here is the piece of code I used for highlighting it red and grey:

```
$("#fname").bind('focus', function (e) {
    if ((document.getElementById("fname").value).length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("fname_error").style.display = "inline";
        $("#fname").attr('style', 'border: 1px solid #8C0005 !important;');

        return false;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("fname_error").style.display = "none";
    }
    return true;
});

$("#fname").keypress(function (e) {
    var iKeyCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode


    if ((iKeyCode > 64 && iKeyCode < 91) || (iKeyCode > 96 && iKeyCode <      123) || iKeyCode==8 || iKeyCode == 9 ) {

                document.getElementById("fname_error").style.display = "none";
                $("#fname").attr('style', 'border: 1px solid #cccccc !important;');
                return true;

    }
    else {
            document.getElementById("fname_error").style.display = "inline";
            return false;
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are setting the red border inside `focus` event handler, and this event can not bi fired if the element is already focused.

Try moving this code to `keyup` handler.

Comment: I replaced focus word with keyup but by this when I click on the textbox it is not highlighting to red now, only keyup event is working.

Comment: I combined both focus and keyup and it worked. Thanks for the help!